# How to programmatically check if the desktop experience is installed or not on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c++, windows, windows-server-2016

As we know Windows Server 2016 comes with an option to install the Desktop Experience during the OS installation, If this is done, the below program snippet fails to detect even though Desktop Experience is installed.

```
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hr = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT ID FROM Win32_ServerFeature"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE,1,&pclsObj,&uReturn);
        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }
        VARIANT vtProp;
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ID",0,&vtProp,0,0);
```

This pEnumerator variable does not contain the Desktop Experience Feature ID which is 35.

Is this an expected behavior in Windows Server 2016?

If not how do we get this value in Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 1):

The registry key in this [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391629(v=vs.85).aspx) is still valid, even though the other methods no longer work on 2016.

If you want to pull the value from the registry, it's in the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallationType
```

For 2016 Desktop Experience, the REG_SZ Value is "Server"
For 2016 the value is "Server Core"

Windows 2016 doesn't consider the Desktop Experience to be a feature since it can no longer be changed on the fly.